# Yii2 - minSize and maxSize of the file validator apply to how many files?

Tags: validation, file-upload, yii2, multi-upload

From the [Core Validators](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#file) guide, the `minSize` and `maxSize` are described as

> the minimum/maximum number of bytes required for the uploaded file.

But there's no explanation on how many files these properties apply to.

Is it per file or total size of all files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In validator code it checks size in method [`validateValue()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/FileValidator.php#L225), so it's min/max size per file, not for all of them.

From [line 207](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/FileValidator.php#L207):

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $result = $this->validateValue($file);
...
```

---

Error example:

```
[
    "The file \"git-flow cheatsheet.png\" is too big. Its size cannot exceed 819.2 KiB.",
    "The file \"IMG_20170531_134929.jpg\" is too big. Its size cannot exceed 819.2 KiB.",
    "The file \"Lenovo sound recorder icon.jpg\" is too small. Its size cannot be smaller than 409.6 KiB.",
    "The file \"memorable-linux-milestone_502911b05dc45.jpg\" is too small. Its size cannot be smaller than 409.6 KiB."
]
```

Comment: Well, I still have to prove it.

Comment: [In code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/FileValidator.php) - line 233.

Comment: Okay, I have confirmed it. The properties apply per file. So let me add the error example for the proof!